# Batch file; Echo to file produces Partial text, while output to screen is full text

Tags: batch-file

This is what I have, the main issue is the partial text, the end result I need is just the first 13 Characters, so any input on that would be icing on the cake.

Data2Del.txt:

```
221459x4ffrd E:\APPSFromXP\expired\tst\5145V.mdb
389231x4ffrd E:\APPSFromXP\expired\tss\5674.dbf    
295279x4ffrd E:\APPSFromXP\expired\tss\5504.dbf
```

Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set Test=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Data2Del.txt) do (
SET /A Test=!Test! + 1
set var!Test!=%%A
echo !%%A!>> Test--OK-2-DELETE--xx.txt

)
set var
pause
```

The Set Var output is correct;
The Test--OK-2-DELETE--xx.txt output starts at "\Apps......

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please did I do something wrong, the code and data are displayed incorrectly, this is my first post on your site.

Comment: To hilight code, either indent each line 4 spaces or select and push `{}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it's happening, but the cause of your issue is the `!`s that you have around %%A. Remove them and it will work.

```
echo %%A>> Test--OK-2-DELETE--xx.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set Test=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (q29037494.txt) do (
 SET /A Test=!Test! + 1
 set var!Test!=%%A
 SET "anothervar=%%A"
 echo !anothervar:~0,13!>> u:\q29037494d.txt
)
set var
GOTO :EOF
```

I've changed the filenames to suit my setup.

This should produce

```
221459x4ffrd 
389231x4ffrd 
295279x4ffrd
```

appended to your file. I note you say "13 characters" which includes the spaces following the first string. An explicit example of the desired output derived from the input would have been useful.

This is one of several ways that the output could have been derived, but explicitly uses batch's substringing function

The substring syntax is

```
%var:~start,length% if start >=0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start >=0 and endpos <0
%var:~start,length% if start <0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start <0 and endpos <0
```

- length/endpos may be omitted. If omitted, the substring is "from the start position to the end"
- `%` may be `!` for `delayedexpansion` mode

and this function cannot be applied to a metavariable like `%%A`

Frankly, why you got the output you had is a mystery to me.